# Installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on iMac 8,1 hardware - Not recognizing the partition now

Tags: boot, ssd

In addition to the title information I successfully installed the version along with the hardware support for WiFi and such. I then attempted to update something (not sure now what it was) and the device froze for a long time. Not sure what to do I restarted it and instead of booting it just goes to the white screen with a folder and question mark. It was working fine for the 30 minutes I had it up prior to whatever update I attempted. This iMac has a single 500GB Samsung SSD installed instead of the old HDD.

Looking for troubleshooting steps to recover the installation or partition the drive but have not been able to see it from the grub tool using the installer USB.

I am writing this on a similar old iMac 7,1 which is great because I have breathed new life into these great machines which I had added memory and SSD's to a number of years ago.

TYIA...

Updated Info - This installation is not a dual boot with Mac OS. The Mac OS was so far out of date I was looking for a use for these computers in my amateur radio shack.

I have used the installer USB to go into the trial mode and launched the disk utility and also the terminal but again the only drive available was the 8GB USB and CD-ROM.

Comment: Well it's an old one so you don't have a T2 security chip to worry about. If you spam the control key (or alt key left of spacebar) when it turns on (with the USB with the Ubuntu *.iso burned on it plugged in) do you get a Mac boot option still?

Comment: I am going back and updating the boot list as I had modified it to ignore 0080 and only use 0000. I am also burning an old Mac El Capitan USB to try and recover it using the Mac OS tools and try to start over. I hope I have not lost the Samsung EVO 500GB drive.